# query gremlin through java

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I have to use a query gremlin in java, and I don't know how can I do, because I've tried to follow the instructions in 
https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java but I have no results, only exception. Someone help me please.

Here is an example of the query that I have to use :

```
 g.V.filter{it.AffiliatedDepartment != null}.copySplit(_().DepartmentDirector, _().inE.filter{it.label == 'Affiliated_Professor'}.outV.AffiliatedProfessor).fairMerge.
```

I tried in both the ways suggested by the official documentation.
Compiling Gremlin Groovy:

```
    Pipe pipe = Gremlin.compile("_().filter{it.AffiliatedDepartment != null}.copySplit(_().DepartmentDirector, _().inE.filter{it.label == 'Affiliated_Professor'}.outV.AffiliatedProfessor).fairMerge");
    pipe.setStarts(g.getVertices());
```

I get a java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: asMap

Using JSR 223 GremlinGroovyScriptEngine:

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("gremlin-groovy");
    List results = new ArrayList();
    Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
    bindings.put("g", g);
    bindings.put("v", g.getVertices()); 
    engine.eval("v.filter{it.AffiliatedDepartment != null}.copySplit(_().DepartmentDirector, _().inE.filter{it.label == 'Affiliated_Professor'}.outV.AffiliatedProfessor).fairMerge", bindings);
```

I get a javax.script.ScriptException with message:

```
<p>groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:</p>
<p>No signature of method: com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jVertexIterable.filter() is applicable for argument types:
</div>
<div>
    (Script1$_run_closure1) values: [Script1$_run_closure1@5bcf59f5]
    </p>
    <p>Possible solutions: find(), first(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), sleep(long), with(groovy.lang.Closure) at
        com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:110) at
        javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the ScriptEngine approach, does it work if you change this line:

```
engine.eval("v.filter{it.AffiliatedDepartment != null}.copySplit(_().DepartmentDirector, _().inE.filter{it.label == 'Affiliated_Professor'}.outV.AffiliatedProfessor).fairMerge", bindings);
```

to

```
engine.eval("g.V.filter{it.AffiliatedDepartment != null}.copySplit(_().DepartmentDirector, _().inE.filter{it.label == 'Affiliated_Professor'}.outV.AffiliatedProfessor).fairMerge", bindings);
```

or to

```
engine.eval("v._().filter{it.AffiliatedDepartment != null}.copySplit(_().DepartmentDirector, _().inE.filter{it.label == 'Affiliated_Professor'}.outV.AffiliatedProfessor).fairMerge", bindings);
```

Setting the `v` binding to `g.getVertices()` sets it to a Neo4jVertexIterable which doesn't recognize `filter` (as `filter` would be found as part of pipeline).  So my theory with both suggestions is to eval a properly formed pipeline.

Comment: Ah. You beat me by a minute. This should work. Prior he was using a `VertexIterable` where gremlin was expecting a `Pipeline` object.

Answer (score 0):

Using version 2.2 and the exception is:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ASMAP.

Instead with version 2.3 I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.FluentUtility.prepareFunction(Lcom/tinkerpop/pipes/util/structures/AsMap;Lcom/tinkerpop/pipes/PipeFunction;)Lcom/tinkerpop/pipes/PipeFunction;

However, the query works fine in console

Comment: Does you original gremlin run in the REPL?  What version of Gremlin are you using?